# React js get value of component's state from container

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a component called `<MultiSelect />`. In the component contains it's own state. I need to get value from it to the parent container. How could I perform this?

MultiSelect:

```
  state = {
    multi: null,
  }

  handleChange = (name) => (value) => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    })
  }

return (
  <div className={classes.root}>
    <NoSsr>
      <Select
        classes={classes}
        styles={selectStyles}
        textFieldProps={{
          label: 'Label',
          InputLabelProps: {
            shrink: true,
          },
        }}
        options={diagnosticCodes}
        components={components}
        value={this.state.multi}
        onChange={this.handleChange('multi')}
        placeholder="Select multiple countries"
        isMulti
      />
    </NoSsr>
  </div>
)
```

I want value of `{this.state.multi}` in Parent Container. I can't define state and handle onChange event from outside because the `<MultiSelect />` is in a `map` so if I try to handle the change outside, all of them takes same state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a method present on the parent Component To the `MultiSelect` component

ParentComponent.js:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
    }

    handleSelect(selectedValue) {
       //handle selected value
   }


   render() {
      return <MultiSelect  handleSelect={this.handleSelect} />
   }
}
```

MultiSelectComponent.js

```
handleChange = (name) => (value) => {
   this.setState({
     [name]: value,
   }, () => this.props.handleSelect(this.state.multi)); //Call the method in the callback of setState
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. I was able to solve this using same trick. But in the `MultiSelectComponent.js` we need to do `() => this.props.handleSelect(value)` instead of `(this.state.multi)`. this.state.multi is giving previous state not the updated one.